# How can we include a search bar to navigate within the same page by comparing the words in markdown language?

Tags: javascript, php, html, markdown, searchbar

I want to include a search bar in my web page that will take me to the location in that page using the word that is given in the search, i want to code this using markdown language. 
Can html,php and javascript be embedded in markdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with markdown. You can do it with javascript, so you might want to convert your md into a static website,

Mkdocs is a good solution. It will generate static html files and a full text index so you can search within your document.

You have to generate the site with python, but you can do whatever you like with the code it generates (edit the style, embed in an iframe) https://www.mkdocs.org/

Good luck